# Pass on vars during paypal payment

Tags: php, variables, paypal, paypal-ipn

How do I pass on vars during a paypal payment?
I would like to get the user's id and the item number back (when transaction is completed).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it does not appear the api return a userid or email that i can find- but it does require you send it.  there is a transaction number that can be cross referenced in your own database - here is a link for more reading.

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APExecutePaymentAPI

I recommend maintaining all the customer information in your own database, and when using the api call, since you will receive an immediate ack, you will know if it is successful - and can use that to trigger a write to your database of the same information you just sent, along with the response.